# How do I remove 'playerachievementcache.dat' from my GMS project?

Tags: game-maker, windows, file

I am working with a GameMaker: Studio project that outputs a file called "playerachievementcache.dat". It isn't used for anything, and I can't seem to remove it from my project. Is it possible that this is something the studio automatically includes? Any ideas on how to locate what is creating the file?

Comment: Why don't ask GMS' developers on official [forum](http://forum.yoyogames.com)?